# Unable to connect to SSH neither throught cloud shell or SCP

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, file-permissions

Before this error happens:

1. I have a VM, I tried to change the permission of all folders to 777, in order to get past an error from data transfer to Cloud Run.
2. leads to "sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set" when I use SSH
3. I fixed it by mounting this infected disk to a temp Instance , changed it back with "chmod 755 /etc/sudo.conf
   chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo"

[image]

Now,

I have 2 problems.

1. I still not able to connect to SSH.

[image]

I tried troubleshooting and all ticks are green, and I did not have an IAP problem before.

Nor FTP (I use Puttygen to create a private key then update VM's meta)

2. the 20 GB disk became 65 GB. Is this what caused the problem? anyway to revert back to 20GB without damaging the disk

[image]

Right now, I can still access the site, it runs fine. https://www.nasavape.com